# Why vent on first floor blows cold air mostly and hot air sometimes?

Tags: heating, furnace, vent, ducts

My house has 3 floors and gas furnace is on 3rd floor. First floor has total of 3 vents but one of those blows cold air most of the time and hot air rarely. The other 2 vents on the same floor blows hot air as per my thermostat setting.

Not sure what causes it to blow cold air most of the time even though setting on the thermometer is HEAT and other vents on the same floor blows hot air and work as expected.

I called a HVAC guy to look into it and when he came, it was blowing hot air. So there was nothing for him to really troubleshoot:

But here are the reasons he said and I thought after reading some info online.

1. He said something like this vent is the farthest from the furnace. But why is it only this vent? There are other vents on the same floor and it doesn't happen with those vents.
2. After looking at the ducts in the attic, he said there is too much slack in those ducts and we need to replace all of these. I was least convinced with this reason as it seemed like he was looking for work to make money.
3. He also said maybe you are feeling cold air to the hand but it is hot air. He asked me to use thermometer gun next time I feel cold air to check true temperature of air coming out of the vent. Not convinced with this as well. Why I experience this with only this vent when other 2 vents on the same floor work fine.
4. Tested with a dollar bill to check if it is a return vent and it is not.
5. Not convinced that there are any leaks in the duct as well because if that is the case, why it blows hot air sometimes.

At this point, I am kind of confused as why this one vent on the first floor blows cold air all the time and hot air seldom.

Comment: Can you figure out more details about "sometimes"? At the beginning of each heating cycle, or perhaps at the beginning of the day/evening, or when a door is open, a bathroom or hood fan is running etc...

Comment: In addition to P2000's question, I think it's important which vent is the one blowing cold air. If it's off the same duct as the others, it may be that the furnace is just not blowing air hard enough to get to it. In any case, something is happening before the hot air gets to that vent (either a leak, an obstruction in the duct, or the air being given a twisty path that's difficult to flow through). But without more information it's hard to diagnose what might be happening.